# EF Core - possible to reference DBSets as string variables or properties?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Writing a table-driven data mapping engine, which references its tables as variables/properties.

But how to execute methods on List objects when they are identified as the value of a property?

...for Example, in literal code, with a dbSet "Customers" and dbContext "dbc", one could insert a Customer record with :

**dbc.Customers.Add(Customer);**

But if "Customers" is identified as a variable...

**var dbSetName = "Customers"**

...is there some way to abstractly execute the same record insertion, e.g.:

**dbc.[dbSetName].Add(Customer)**

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `Add` method on `DbContext`.

```cs
dbc.Add(Customer);
```